# Splitting string into different arrays of types using regex

Tags: java, arrays, string

What's the easiest and most effective way to spit a string into different arrays of types? Example:

```
String[] textArr; 
String[] numbersArr;
```

and if possible a `String[] doubleArr` and a `String[] dateArray`z

```
//the string I want to split
String splitMe = "Tinus has 99 issues and has to pay $2200.50 for 26 on 2016/10/10";
```

After it's split it should be

```
String[] textArr = ["Tinus","has","issues","and","to","pay","for","on"]; 
String[] numbersArr = ["99","26"];
String[] doubleArr = ["2200.50"];
String[] dateArr = ["2016/10/10"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might opt for just splitting the input string by space, and then using a pattern match to check each entry to determine where it belongs:

```
String splitMe = "Tinus has 99 issues and has to pay $2200.50 for 26 on 2016/10/10";
String[] parts = splitMe.split(" ");
List<String> textList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> currencyList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String part : parts) {
    if (part.matches("\\d*")) {
        numbersList.add(part);
    }
    else if (part.matches("\\$\\d*\\.\\d*")) {
        currencyList.add(part);
    }
    else if (part.matches("\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}")) {
        dateList.add(part);
    }
    else {
        textList.add(part);
    }
}
```

I didn't attempt to formally extract a double from the currency.  And I also chose to use lists rather than arrays to store the various terms, because this will scale better.  I will leave it up to you to fill in the details.

Comment: Quick and great answer thanks. I was thinking about using lists rather than arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String splitMe = "Tinus has 99 issues and has to pay $2200.50 for 26 on 2016/10/10";


String[] splitArray = splitMe.split(" ");
System.out.println("splitArray: " + Arrays.toString(splitArray));

String[] tmp = new String[splitArray.length];        

int i = 0;
for (String s : splitArray) {
    if (s.matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        tmp[i] = s;
        i++;
    }         
}     

String[] textArr = new String[i];
for (int j = 0; j < textArr.length; j++) {
    textArr[j] = tmp[j];
}

tmp = new String[splitArray.length];

i = 0;
for (String s : splitArray) {
    if (s.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        tmp[i] = s;
        i++;
    } 
}

String[] numbersArr = new String[i];
for (int j = 0; j < numbersArr.length; j++) {
    numbersArr[j] = tmp[j];
}

tmp = new String[splitArray.length];

i = 0;
for (String s : splitArray) {
    if (s.matches("\\$[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")) {
        tmp[i] = s;
        i++;
    } 
}

String[] doubleArr = new String[i];
for (int j = 0; j < doubleArr.length; j++) {
    doubleArr[j] = tmp[j];
}

tmp = new String[splitArray.length];

i = 0;
for (String s : splitArray) {
    if (s.matches("[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+")) {
        tmp[i] = s;
        i++;
    }
}

String[] dateArr = new String[i];
for (int j = 0; j < dateArr.length; j++) {
    dateArr[j] = tmp[j];
}

System.out.println("textArr: " + Arrays.toString(textArr));
System.out.println("numbersArr: " + Arrays.toString(numbersArr));
System.out.println("doubleArr: " + Arrays.toString(doubleArr));
System.out.println("dateArr: " + Arrays.toString(dateArr));
```

Please note that the regex used are not ideal but they work for your case. I used arrays because I thought it is a strict requirement. You can use lists as well which is better.

Comment: You're right that using lists is better, and it's better even if you need arrays.  In that case, it's best to create an `ArrayList` and convert it to an array at the end with `toArray`.  Also note that this answer will work a bit different from Tim's, in the way it handles parts that don't fit any of your four regexes (e.g. words that have `'` or `-` characters in them).  This isn't right or wrong, since the OP didn't specify whether text parts had to be all letters.